# What good is Friends?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, cantrips

I've been looking at the [Friends](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/friends) cantrip, and the more I think about it the *less* useful it appears.

It appears to be self-defeating: you can gain advantage in a conversation, but they'll know you manipulated them pretty quickly. You might use it to bypass a guard, but they're all too likely to shout “Intruder!” once it wears off. You could use it on a merchant, but they're all too likely to turn adversarial afterwards, leaving you disadvantaged for the entire duration of your stay in town.

You *can't* use it to help with someone actively hostile to you, such as during an interrogation, eliminating the kinds of uses where it doesn't matter if they catch on after.

So what exactly is Friends for?

Comment: These are not the Warforged you are looking for...

Answer (score 40, accepted):

*Friends* is good for problems that can't be solved by killing people. For example, if you need to get through a gate, and the guard knows the password, killing him won't get you that password. Casting *Friends* on him, persuading him to tell you the password, and *then* killing him is a much better plan.

"But you could just force him to tell you the password!" Well, possibly. Loyalty comes into play here, and it's important to remember that the DM has every motivation to make his guards fanatically loyal.

In general, *Friends* is primarily useful to help you get information. Yes, you'll have to deal with the person afterwards, but you would have had to do that if you'd gotten the information by threatening to kill them. This way, they should give you correct information; getting information by threatening them is a great way to get information that leads to your death.

A secondary use is getting people to do things they wouldn't normally do. This sounds obvious, but (to stay consistent), imagine we have another gate, only this one has a guard *behind* it. He won't open the gate for you normally, but with the help of *Friends* you might be able to talk him into it. Obviously, once you're inside you'll probably have to kill him.

Comment: To sum up: "What good is the Friends spell?" "It can make people like you before you murder them."

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58301/discussion-on-answer-by-miniman-what-good-is-friends). (If this room is deleted and you would like to see it, please raise a custom flag for a moderator to undelete it).

Comment: Also, you can use it to buy you some time, like if you're in a disguise and say, "the wizard went that way," before escaping out the door. I like to call it the "Bugs Bunny Approach".

Answer (score 11):

### Friends is a useful cantrip for dealing with people you don't expect to ever have to deal with again.

- You need to lie to that goblin to get him to come around a corner so
  your friends can murder him?  Friends.
- You want to pass off some counterfeit coinage to a merchant while
  under the effect of Disguise Self right before you skip town?
  Friends.
- You want to lie to a mercenary to get him to lower his guard right
  before you escape your shackles and make off into the forest?
  Friends.

It also works for people who already dislike you.  Are they gonna
dislike you more because you used mind magic to trick them?  Maybe.
But you're losing very little either way.

It lacks verbal components and the material component is a 'dab of makeup', so it's very reasonable to at least attempt to conceal it being cast (as appears to be the intent).

Like any other social interaction it will depend on your table and DM how effective it can be (there are games where outside of the DM asking for a pre-scripted roll, social interaction may as well not exist - there are also games where social engineering and political maneuver on massive scales vastly eclipse the miniatures combat).

But in effect, Friends should be thought of the same way fast talking someone should be.  It works once, and then they realize they were hoodwinked, and hate you.  It's just the magical version of being a con-man.  And for a cantrip, the bonus it gives is rather hefty, especially at tables where DM's don't allow the Help action to be used like a bandaid coverall on every single non-combat roll.

Comment: +1 good examples. It also gives advantage on all Charisma checks, so it can be used not just to persuade or deceive, but also to intimidate. The con-man can be scary sometimes, too. :)

Answer (score 3):

Cantrip's are not supposed to be powerful.  Mind Control spells are dangerous to use on any level and often are extremely illegal in any civilized setting. Friends is 100% a 'last ditch effort' to COMPLETE a task before booking it out of there.

You don't use friends on a merchant so you can bargain with them. This wastes valuable time after casting it. You use friends on a merchant so you can buy something that someone else commissioned and you are going to over pay for it. The point is to convince them, to take this profit because their FRIEND is willing to compensate them for the item taking 2 weeks longer to complete or what ever inconvenience it will cause them.  Consider what you are willing to do for your friends in regards to your job/business.

You don't use friends on your landlord to cut the cost of this months rent. You do use it on the guard to get THROUGH the gates of the city and then quickly disappear into the ally ways and side streets... don't hang out casually in the bar on the other side of the gate.  Get through, and get gone.

The spell is a great way to accomplish A L O T... but it is a niche.  Having it might mean never using it, because it tends to be too risky.  If you play in a game where inspiration is handed out like candy, it might NEVER be worth risking.  But, friends is extremely powerful when it is wisely used.

To me, this is one of the things with many interpretations of many cantrips.  They are not meant to be powerful.  They are meant to be 'babies first...' Consider how One DnD is playtesting Guidance as a reaction, and limits it to once a long rest per person it effects.  I try to consider balancing all cantrips toward each other using things like prestidigitation as a base level.  Cantrips are simply the at will spells on hand.  The utility of Friends, is in the ONE time you NEED it, not always using it, but using it when it is absolutely necessary and when either you, or its target are going to be gone in the next 45 seconds.  You or Them... someone has to disappear be it by disguise, into the throng, or by death.

Comment: *Consider how One DnD is playtesting Guidance as a reaction, and limits it to once a long rest per person it effects* They already changed that because the feedback indicated it was a bad idea

Comment: I think using guidance as a reaction is an amazing change, I think the once per long rest was a heavy weight to put on it.  I hate guidance, I usually let people know well a head of choosing it, that at my table there is no yelling GUIDANCE because dice. The party better learn, the cleric can and will guide someone who plots and plans things a head of time. Cleric prays with you, then go do your thing. @KorvinStarmast

Comment: One of the things I was thinking about was also that Friends is as simple as complimenting someone whilst putting on some lip balm, or charcoal as eye liner... you could be in prison and easily manage 'makeup' to cast this and get free.  1 minute is a lot of time in some situations that are game saving.

Answer (score 3):

None of the answers seems to have mentioned the possibility of using the *guaranteed* hostility side effect. It seems that one could use friends with reverse psychology to sow discontent/encourage loyalty (this might assume the target of the charisma check is not familiar with the cantrip and merely recognizes an attempt to be charmed). "Isn't Lord Grom great/horrible ..."

Similarly, such could draw attention to an issue when one would not normally be able to convince someone to give it attention. "You don't really need to check the fodder for poison, afterall no one could get through to poison it." under friends might be more effective at getting someone to check the fodder than an anonymous tip.

Forewarning a guard captain of an attempt to charm a guard to gain entry might also be used to establish credibility as an informer, which might be useful. While an ordinary bribery attempt to pass a guard might be sufficient, use of magic would increase the perception of threat and motivate at least the targeted guard to make a fuss.

Alteration of behavior from multiple castings (against one person or multiple persons) might also draw attention — "That's the third time this month the second watch uncovered a plot" or "Sergeant Sterm is getting paranoid, that's the third time this month we've had to check for sabotage for no good reason." This might help get a more exploitable person promoted to a position concerned in a later action or a more competent, less exploitable person promoted out of such a position or the opposite in encouraging competence in an area (as an ally or having a common adversary).

The direction of the hostility might also be useful. Hostility can direct the target's attention to the spell caster, encouraging the target to do something unwise like leaving a guard post to chase the caster or at least facilitating someone else sneaking by. If the caster is disguised, the hostility might be misdirected by mistaken identity. Hostility toward a class of persons might also be encouraged — "That peddler tried to trick me with magic. You can't trust peddlers." — which could encourage long-term actions against that class of persons.

The friends cantrip might be more effective for starting a tavern brawl (for distraction or getting someone in trouble) than insults (alone).

The effectiveness of many of these strategies would depend on unfamiliarity with the specifics of the friends cantrip. Impulsive actions from hostility might not be much reduced from an awareness of the specific short duration and limited effect of the charm. If the target (and any indirectly influenced) only recognize that magic was used against the target and not the specific, limited magic, even longer-term behavior could be motivated by someone trying to use magic in this way.

Answer (score 2):

### Friends is a narrow and weak cantrip

Kudos [to Miniman](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/62164/75095) for finding at least *one* fringe situations where the spell could be of use, getting the guard to open the gate or share the password, before you have to kill them.

But the reality of the matter is: you read that right, friends is a horribly weak spell, due to its short duration of only "Concentration, up to 1 minute". Lets look at what it does:

> For the duration, you have advantage on all Charisma checks directed at one creature of your choice that isn’t hostile toward you.  When the spell ends, the creature realizes that you used magic to influence its mood and becomes hostile toward you. (...)

**The effect is weak**: You need to be in a situation where the other party is not already opposed to you, like on the bazaar, in an inn, or at the gate of a castle. If you are in such a situation, it does not even get you automatic success: all it does it give you better odds on a charisma check that you already could do. And it will entirely up to the DM how to interpret that successful check or decide what it could achieve. For example, it is possible they decide a guard has been instructed to *under no circumstances* share the password with strangers, and so the DM might decide there is no chance of success and may allow you to make that check to begin with.

**The effect is hard to get**: Another issue is that usually casting spells at someone in a social situation out of the blue is not proper social ettiquette, and can be considered as offensive. People who cast spells at shopkeepers or guards often are up to no good, if it's *charm person*, *dominate person*, *friends*, or whatever. If you try casting a spell that may well be a reason the DM decides they turn hostile and asks for rolling initiative to see if you get it off before they can react. If they turn hostile before you can get it off, it will not work at all.

**The effect is too short-lived to be useful**: The kicker is that even if you successfully pull it off, and you succeed on both casting the spell without turning them hostile first and on your charisma check, they *automatically will turn hostile and know what happened at most a minue later*. This is awful: if you convinced the shopkeeper to sell you something cheaper, they will cry foul and get the guards. If you convinced the guard to let you through, conning them that you're from the delivery service, they will raise the alarm. And so on. Social situations normally do not operate on round-by-round combat time scales. If the duration was an hour or so, to allow you to get away in time before they realize what happend it might work. One minute, in nearly all circumstances won't cut it.

And of course as you say, for getting the truth out of prisoners instead of threatening them with death, it is no use: they are *already* hostile to you.

So in summary, unless your DM agrees that this spell is so bad that it is essentially useless, and turns a blind eye towards the negative side effects to fix it, this spell is not going to do what its name advertises. It  is *not* going to win you friends and make you charming. It will turn everyone you try it on into being hostile towards you in no time. Don't waste your valuable cantrip picks on it.