# Limitations of targeting of 'Friends' cantrip

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, targeting, cantrips

The "Friends" cantrip (PHB pg 244) has a range of "self", but it also affects "one creature of your choice".  Can this creature be one you can't see, such as one behind a door?

This question: [What good is Friends?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/62153/what-good-is-friends) includes comments about using the cantrip against a guard on the other side of a gate, but I get the impression that the caster would be able to see the target in that scenario.

I'm looking for answers based on the RAW; if there's another spell which has a range of "self" but still only effects a specified target other than the caster, that would be a big help for comparison.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## KISS Principle

**Treat *Friends* as a Buff(self) and the Complication Goes Away**

Pursuing the "target" word in the rules is an over complication that misses the point of the spell.  While cantrips are not particularly powerful magic, a buff is a buff.

In the case of *Friends*, the limitation is that you can't BS a group of people but you *can* BS one person a little better than usual when using a Charisma based Skill.  Until you make a Charisma based interaction with that creature, *Friends* doesn't do anything at all.  **Friends is a catalyst or enhancement for your subsequent action, or an attempt at Persuasion.  It does not create an independent affect on another creature.**

Two examples to illustrate the serial nature of a buff:

1. I cast *Bless* on our party's Barbarian when we encounter an Ogre.  The *Bless* doesn't influence the Ogre unless the Barbarian does something to the Ogre while under the *Bless* buff.  If he makes an attack on the Ogre, then the *Buff* can have an impact on the Ogre who now has an increased chance to be hit/hurt.  If I *bless* the Barbarian but he doesn't attack the Ogre, *Bless* does nothing to the Ogre.  The Barbarian has to *Choose* to attack the Ogre for the buff to matter.  (Just as with friends you have to *Choose* to activate the affect of the cantrip).
2. My wife goes to buy a car.  The car salesman does his best to influence/persuade her via the usual sales tactics. (*Friends* cantrip analogy).  He's got more chance of success if she's alone.  With me or her mother (a shrewd bargainer) sitting beside her the salesman might convince her with his smooth talking ploy - but neither of us since he's directing his charm at my wife.  Like the *Friends* spell, once it's over my wife is likely to be annoyed/pissed at the car salesman for laying all of that charm/ on her after his "spell" wears off.

Some of the higher level influence spells, like *suggestion* or *Charm*, also require a serial action be directed at the creature or the *Charm* itself doesn't really do anything.

*Friends* limits your ability to be charming/persuasive to one creature.  You choose the one to whom you want to be more charming/friendly.

Compare *Friends* to a Cantrip like Sacred Flame: in that case, the *target* is directly affected by damage (or save to avoid damage).  No second/serial action by the Cleric is required to create the damage affect.

> Can this creature be one you can't see, such as one behind a door?

If you have a way to interact with that creature behind the door, a way that takes advantage of your Charisma, of course.

Consider this: a blind man can't see you, but he can interact with you, and perhaps try to Persuade you to do something.  (He may have advantage in doing so when you are both in complete darkness!)

Comment: I'm wondering how the second half of the spell would be handled. "When the spell ends, the creature realizes that you used magic to influence its mood and becomes hostile toward you." RAW there doesn't seem to be a requirement for the caster to interact with the target for this to take effect.

Comment: Hmm, if the caster never interacts with the other creature, I don't think there's a trigger for the hostility.  Let me get back to you on that, and maybe that's a related but separate question. 

Answer (score 7):

You do not have to be able to see the creature you are effecting but you must be able to interact sufficiently that a Charisma check is required.

The target of the spell is "Self". Therefore the targeting rules apply to you; you always have a line of effect to yourself and you can always touch yourself (although it is not polite to do it in public).

After that "... you have advantage on all Charisma 
checks directed at one creature of  your choice that isn’t 
hostile toward you." There is no requirement to "target" them, you "choose" them. You need to interact with that creature to cause the Charisma check but the interaction could be shouting through a closed door, talking to an invisible creature or choosing the King *before* you enter the throne room.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31000/discussion-between-dafluid-and-pitzy).

Answer (score -2):

According to the PHB (*Targets*, p.203), **you must have a clear path to your target**, so it can't be behind total cover.

If the target is behind a door, the door must have some sizable crack or opening through which you have a clear path to the target. Using a mirror to peek around the door and see the target while staying on the other side of the door does not count as a clear path. ;)

---

To clarify: My position here stems from the interpretation that **Friends creates a magical effect that affects both the caster and the other creature**. As such, without any *specific* rules of targeting, I am saying that the other creature is subject to the *general* rules of spell-targeting, which then requires a clear path to the target.

With regard to the lack of range for this targeting: It doesn't matter to me. If you can sense the creature well enough and there is a clear path between you, then it's a valid target. ^_^

Comment: @KorvinStarmast : I don't see the difference. "Targeting" or "targets" as terms aren't consistently used in spell descriptions. Consider *Acid Splash* (Choose one creature...choose two creatures), *Detect Thoughts* (If the creature you choose), *Alarm* (Choose a door), *Animal Friendship* (Choose a beast), and so on. You aren't telling me that those spells don't follow "targeting rules", are you?

Comment: @Pitzy If you don't see a difference, then we'll just agree to disagree.  Happy gaming.