# Can I only target other creatures, not myself, when casting spells such as Invisibility that target "a creature you touch"?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, targeting

Invisibility reads: "**A creature you touch** becomes invisible until the spell ends..."

Greater Invisibility says: "**You or a creature you touch** becomes invisible until the spell ends..."

By omission, does this suggest that one cannot use Invisibility on oneself?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

### Yes, you can touch yourself.

The PHB clarifies this under page 201:

> ### Targeting Yourself
>
> If a spell targets a creature of your choice, you can choose yourself, unless the creature must be hostile or specifically a creature other than you.

On the inconsistencies of the wordings for Invisibility and Greater Invisibility:

I would pay it no mind, the PHB even has inconsistencies in the Great Weapon Fighting feature of the Fighter versus the Paladin.

Comment: I do not claim to be original. http://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/70604/23064 http://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/46372/23064

Answer (score 18):

The Range section of the Spellcasting chapter answers this explicitly:

> Most spells have ranges expressed in feet. Some spells can target only a creature (**including you**) that you touch.

So any spell that targets a creature you touch can be used on yourself.

Answer (score 5):

#### No, you can target yourself.

The rules work under the premises that if something is not expressively prohibited then is legal to do so. For example, Bardic Inspiration (emphasis mine) tells you specifically that you cannot be the target.

> **Bardic Inspiration:** To do so, you use a bonus action on your turn to choose one creature **other than yourself** within 60 feet of you
> who can hear you.