# Can the Remove Curse spell be cast on yourself?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Can a Remove curse spell be cast on yourself? If all allies of Von Richten are cursed for helping him in Curse of Strahd, why does he just cast Remove curse on himself?

Comment: Hi Kerry, welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] to find out how things work here and visit the [help] for more info. I've updated the title of your question to better reflect the question, and no need to put D&D 5e in the title since we'll know what game it is thanks to you tagging the question as [dnd-5e] (seriously, thanks for that, tagging is an important part of this site). Happy gaming!

Comment: I've found [this other question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/89570/can-i-only-touch-other-creatures-with-spells-such-as-invisibility?noredirect=1&lq=1), which explores how spells with a range of "Touch" (which Remove Curse has) can be cast on yourself. Even though this other question is about invisibility spells, does this also answer your question about Remove Curse targeting yourself?

Comment: If your question is more about Curse of Strahd storyline than the mechanics of the Remove Curse spell, it might be best to ask that as a more detailed separate question.

Comment: @NathanS there seems to be more to this than just targeting yourself. The OP seems to think this would remove the curses from all of the allies which is not the case. Though I may be interpreting the OP incorrectly.

Comment: This is a pretty big question and answers would do well to delve into what Ravenloft (which is the source of the module and setting) really is as well as possibly how things are just beyond mortal intervention... I don't have the time here at work to make a comprehensive enough answer, just thought I would throw that out there though.

Comment: Or, if this isn't going to be a duplicate, you can just edit this question to focus it more on exactly what Remove Curse does and doesn't do in Curse of Strahd.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, [Remove Curse](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/remove-curse) most certainly can be cast on yourself. [This QA](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/89570/can-i-only-touch-other-creatures-with-spells-such-as-invisibility?noredirect=1&lq=1) (pointed out by [NathanS](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/35259/nathans)) says that you can target yourself if a spell targets a creature of your choice (unless the spell specifically states otherwise). This is also confirmed by the [Player's Handbook](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/phb/spellcasting#TargetingYourself) under the Targeting Yourself section in chapter 10. Remove curse has a range of Touch. The description of the spell states (emphasis mine)

> At your **touch** all curses affecting **one creature** or object end.

As for the second half of your question, I can't answer that as I don't have the book but maybe someone else can who does.